# Is the day-night cycle purely cosmetic?

Tags: defiance

The cycle for this game seems pretty quick.  Is there anything that happens more often, or exclusively, at certain times or parts of the day?

Answer (score 2):

After playing the game for quite awhile, I have to say I think it doesn't have any effect on the gameplay whatsoever apart from obscuring vision slightly.

Because the game is an MMO, it is hard to tell whether this is a server bug, intentional or perhaps they just haven't coded it yet. But no doubt, the game's difficulty doesn't change in any noticeable or dramatic way as a result of the day/night cycle.

(It's possible that this may only apply during certain missions or areas that the difficulty changes, but I am yet to find any official word in regards to whether this is true or not. For now, I would say it's cosmetic.)

Comment: I was thinking maybe certain random events trigger more often at night or something like that.  I've not noticed the difficulty changing either.